# remove extension from filename, but keep extension associated to file

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have been having difficulty loading an .xlsx into a directory and not having .xlsx attached to the filename, but keeping it assocaited to the .xlsx  file type.
This is as close as I could get

```
$maintenance_dir = "C:/wamp/www/mafrd/maintenance/$siteNAME/";
$maintenance_file = $maintenance_dir . basename($_FILES["loadtrip"] ["name"], ".xlsx") .'_'. date("Y-m-d");
if (!file_exists($maintenance_dir)) {
mkdir($maintenance_dir, 0777, true);
}
$uploadOk = 1;

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['loadtrip']['tmp_name'], $maintenance_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["loadtrip"]["name"], ".xlsx") .'_'. date("Y-m-d"). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
```

[image]

It currently comes out as the orange highlighted and I would like it to mirror the yellow.

Comment: Whatever is listing the files shows XLSX only because the extension is .xlsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows, the file type is associated with the filename. You can't remove the .xlsx and expect it to behave as normal.

The solution I would recommend you is to add the date before the extension:

```
 $maintenance_file = $maintenance_dir . basename($_FILES["loadtrip"] ["name"], ".xlsx") .'_'. date("Y-m-d") . ".xlsx";
```

If this is not what you're looking for, you could create a different extension and map it to Excel.

You can still open the file with Excel even if it has a different extension, but it may not open automatically when clicking on the item.

Comment: Windows File Explorer also gives you the option to hide the file extension.... the file is still stored with the extension, and therefore associated with the MS Excel application, but the extension itself isn't displayed in the File Explorer view

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the case on his referenced image as well. 
The solution would work as it is adding the date before adding the extension, which would be hidden.

Comment: Legendary! Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Feel free to mark this topic as "Answered" if you found the answer :)